# Is it alright to install Python on D drive?

Tags: python-3.x

I am embarking on the journey to learn Python and decided to start with Python 3.7.3

However, I had a couple of questions before I install python on my computer.

My C drive is an M.2 SSD with only about 60 GBs of space left in it. I do not know how much space my python projects would take as I go on about educating myself in the language. Hence I wanted to know whether installing Python and an IDE like PyCharm in D drive would work. Would it affect where pip installs Modules and Libraries?

Comment: Why not install Python in the usual spot, and store your *projects* on the D drive?

Comment: @ceejayoz Would it be possible dow install Python in the usual spot but install my IDE in a separate drive?

Comment: @SS_1801 python requires just a few megabytes, feel free to go ahead and install it to your C: drive if that's fine with you - you can always reinstall later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not care where it gets installed as long as you know where it is at and preferably is in your system path.

Might I suggest checking out https://pythonprogramming.net

*EDIT*: Below will print the location of your site packages (aka. the things you pip install)

```
import site
print(site.getsitepackages())
```

One last thing... My suggestion is just install Python to its default.

THEN! `pip install virtualenv`

NEXT `cd` into a directory on your other drive

1. `mkdir my-python-code`
2. `cd my-python-code`
3. `virtualenv --name my-python-env`

Then just use that virtual environment. This does two things for you it uses your other drive like you want. But it also gets you using Virtual Environments early on which is a good habit to be in.

[This](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) might be useful for getting started with `virtualenv`.

Comment: If I do install Python in its regular location, where would the Python Libraries install?

Comment: @SS_1801 into the same drive by default, but you can install them wherever you like as long as you know how to make python find the files. You can _even_ have both at the same time.